# How to generate stream in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-streambuilder

I am making some experiment with flutter stream. I have a class for generating stream of `int`. Here is the class :

```
class CounterRepository {
  int _counter = 123;

  void increment() {
    _counter++;
  }

  void decrement() {
    _counter--;
  }

  Stream<int> watchCounter() async* {
    yield _counter;
  }
}
```

I expect with the change of `_counter`, `watchCounter()` will yield updated `counter` value. When I call `increment()` or `decrement()` from UI, it seems the value of `_counter` is changing but `watchCounter` doesn't yield the updated `_counter` value. How to yield updated `_counter` value here? I am using `StreamBuilder` from UI to get the streamed data.

Comment: use `StreamController` - more here: https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams

Comment: How to add event for `increment` and `decrement` inside `watchCounter()`? Can you please explain with an answer?

Comment: `void increment() => ctrl.add(++_counter);` and `Stream<int> watchCounter() => ctrl.stream;`

Comment: Thanks. One more question, in this case, when  should I close the `StreamController`?

Comment: in `State.dispose` method?

Comment: No, inside `CounterRepository` class. Created the `StreamController` instance in repository. Should it be closed here and when?

Answer (score 1):

You have created your `streams` using  -

```
Stream<int> watchCounter() async* {
    yield _counter;
}
```

But to reflect the changes of your stream, you need to receive those stream events. You can control those stream events using a [StreamController](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-async/StreamController-class.html)

**Creating a stream**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  var stream = watchCounter();
}
```

**Using that stream**

*stream.listen*

> Subscribes to the stream by calling the listen function and supplys it
> with a Function to call back to when there's a new value available.
>
> ```
> stream.listen((value) {   
> print('Value from controller: $value');
> });
> ```

There are many other approaches to control and manage streams but for your particular question `.listen` will do the job.

Comment: Yeah I had to use `StreamController`. `stream.listen` is done internally inside `StreamBuilder` I think.

Comment: @Newaj yes if your are using `StreamControllers`. But I was just telling the way to write streams n stuff

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an infinite while loop, it's a manual stream.

```
Stream<dynamic> watchCounter() async* {
   while (true) {
      // you can change it to 5 seconds or higher
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      yield _counter;
   }
}
```

And after that you just need to call listen:

```
watchCounter().listen((value) {
  // hear can be empty if you want.
});
```

You can put it in your init state to run, don't put it in your widget build, please.

This should work fine